# How to use Bfrtip along with Zlfrtip in datatable dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am using `Bootstrap` dataTable. Also using  `Bfrtip` to display the button like csv, pdf.

Now I want to display columns which can be resizable so I have found this plugin - https://github.com/Silvacom/colResize.

How to use Btrtip along with Zlfrtip? . Buttons and resize column also working well But it is displaying two search box and pagination.

I know there wil be better option to place this thing on dom. I am using as below:

```
 $('#table').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "scrollX": true,
    "dom": 'Bfrtip Zlfrtip',
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
});
```